# Invalid Read size 4

Tags: c, connection

I'm getting Invalid Read, the program works with small files but for big files, I get segmentation faults. Why is this happening, and how to I resolve it?
To sum things up I have a Matrix (tabela) that represents a labyrinth with walls. I have to map the rooms and see if 2 cells are in the same room (room is a place surrounded by walls). To do this I use an algorithm to connect the cells (function cwqu)
The main function:

```
    int *id = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if(id==NULL){
            printf("Erro: Não foi possivel alocar o bloco de memoria");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    int *sz = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if(sz==NULL){
            printf("Erro: Não foi possivel alocar o bloco de memoria");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
   
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         id[i] = i; sz[i] = 1;
    }

    //go through the matrix
    for(r=1;r<=row;r++){
     for(c=1;c<=col;c++){
         //if the cell is white...
         if(tabela[r-1][c-1]==0){
            //...and the one we are comparing it to is also white, connect them
            if(c!=col && tabela[r-1][c+1-1]==0) cwqunion((r-1)*col+c, (r-1)*col+(c+1), id, sz);
            if(r!=row && tabela[r+1-1][c-1]==0) cwqunion((r-1)*col+c, (r)*col+c, id, sz);
         }
     }
    }

    //check if the cells are connected
    for (i = (dados[2]-1+1)*col+dados[3]+1; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
    for (j = (dados[6]-1+1)*col+dados[7]+1; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);

    //if they are connected, return 1 (affirmative), if not, return 0 (negative)
    if(i==j) resultado = 1;
    else resultado = 0;

    //free the arrays
    free(id);
    free(sz);
```

The function it calls:

```
void cwqunion(int p, int q, int *id, int *sz){
    
        int i, j, t, x;

    for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
    for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);

    if (i != j){
        if (sz[i] < sz[j]) {
            id[i] = j; sz[j] += sz[i]; t = j;
        } else {
            id[j] = i; sz[i] += sz[j]; t = i;
        }
        for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = x) {x = id[i]; id[i] = t;}
        for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = x) {x = id[j]; id[j] = t;}
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger to find out the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. That will likely give you a good clue where you might be overrunning buffers or accessing invalid memory in some way. If you still need further help please update with the debugging info you find and provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: The `c+1` in this `(r-1)*col+(c+1)` looks suspicious. Aside: it seems perverse to run a loop to `r<=row` and then put `if(r!=row ...`

Comment: In this loop `for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);` the index `i` is replaced by the value at that index. And there is no precautionary check for a runaway.

Comment: In: `cwqunion` the loops: `for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);` and: `for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);` appear to have no executable statements.